# How can I sort by custom value in NSSortDescriptor?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, nssortdescriptor

I would like to sort an array with calculate distance between current location and map point location. I have done my code as below and I able to get the distance result. May I know how can I sort by distance asc (Near to me) for my case as below?

```
[self.manager GET:@"http://www.samplewebsite.net/api" parameters:nil progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {

        aryNearMeList = responseObject;

        for (int i = 0; i < aryNearMeList.count; i++) {
        CLLocation *merchantLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[[_serverDataArr [i]valueForKey:@"latitude"] doubleValue] longitude:[[_serverDataArr [i]valueForKey:@"longitude"] doubleValue]];
        CLLocationDistance meters = [merchantLocation distanceFromLocation:location];

        NSString *abc = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"~ %.2f km", meters / 1000.0];
        NSLog(@"243 %@",abc);  //WILL RETURN DISTANCE HERE. HOW CAN I SORT BY DISTANCE ASC??
         }

        NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"abc" ascending:YES
    comparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
        float value1 = [obj1 floatValue];
        float value2 = [obj2 floatValue];
        if (value1 == value2) {
            return NSOrderedSame;
        } else if (value1 > value2) { 
            return NSOrderedDescending;
        } else {
            return NSOrderedAscending;
        }
    }];
        _serverDataArr = [aryNearMeList sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        });

    } failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) { }
```

Comment: Does your problem exist still now?

Comment: @ShamimHossain, yes